# VBox Contents Not Filling Window

Tags: java, javafx

For a program I'm working on, I decided to create my own "command prompt", meaning that error messages that would normally be sent to the console are sent to it for debugging. Before, when the only feature was text being displayed, everything worked fine. Now, however, after I made the root a `VBox` instead of a `ScrollPane`, the formatting and layout is weird. Below is the current version of the console, which isn't working, and the previous version, which works fine.

**Old:**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DebugConsoleOld extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, Screen.getPrimary()
                .getVisualBounds().getWidth() - 10, Screen.getPrimary()
                .getVisualBounds().getHeight() - 10);

        scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        box.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        scrollPane.setContent(box);

        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Debug Console");
        stage.show();

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss] ");

        write(new Exception(), Priority.MEDIUM);
        write(new NullPointerException(), Priority.MEDIUM);
        write(new SQLException(), Priority.MEDIUM);
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        message = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + message;
        ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getContent())
            .getChildren().add(textBuilder(message));
    }

    public void write(String message, Priority priority) {
        write(message, priority.color);
    }

    private void write(String message, Color fontColor) {
        message = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + message;
        ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getContent())
            .getChildren().add(
                    textBuilder(message, null, null, 0, fontColor));
    }

    public void write(Exception exception, Priority priority) {
        // exception.printStackTrace();
        write("--- Beginning of Exception ---", Priority.HIGH);
        write(exception.toString(), priority);
        StackTraceElement[] arrayOfStackTraceElement = exception
                .getStackTrace();
        Object localObject2;
        for (StackTraceElement ste : arrayOfStackTraceElement)
            write("\t at " + ste, priority);
        localObject2 = exception.getCause();
        if (localObject2 != null)
            write("Caused by: " + localObject2);
        write("--- End of Exception ---", Priority.HIGH);
    }

    private HBox textBuilder(String text) {
        return textBuilder(text, null, null, 0, null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private HBox textBuilder(String text, FontWeight fontWeight,
            FontPosture fontPosture, double fontSize, Color fontColor) {
        return javafx.scene.layout.HBoxBuilder
                .create()
                .children(javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxBuilder.create().build(),
                    javafx.scene.text.TextBuilder
                            .create()
                            .text(text)
                            .font(Font
                                    .font("Consolas",
                                            (fontWeight == null ? FontWeight.NORMAL
                                                    : fontWeight),
                                                (fontPosture == null ? FontPosture.REGULAR
                                                        : fontPosture),
                                                (fontSize <= 0 ? 13 : fontSize)))
                                .wrappingWidth(
                                        ((ScrollPane) stage.getScene()
                                                .getRoot()).getWidth() - 2)
                                .fill((fontColor == null ? Color.WHITE
                                        : fontColor)).build()).build();
     }

    public int clear() {
        int items = ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot())
                .getChildren().get(0)).getContent()).getChildren().size();
        ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getChildren()
                .get(0)).getContent()).getChildren().clear();
        return items;
    }

    public static enum Priority {
         /**
         * A message of no great importance
          */
         LOW(Color.LIGHTGRAY),
        /**
         * A message of standard importance, or something not necessary to be
         * noticed
         */
        NORMAL(Color.WHITE),
        /**
         * A message of standard importance, but may need developer attention
         */
        MILD(Color.YELLOW),
        /**
         * A message needing attention, as something may have broken
         */
        MEDIUM(Color.ORANGE),
        /**
         * A message of great importance, something broke, an exception was
         * thrown, ect.
         */
        HIGH(Color.RED);

        private Color color;

        private Priority(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Current:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DebugConsoleNew extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 300);
        final TextField commandField = new TextField();

        scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        box.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        scrollPane.setContent(box);
        commandField.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                Color.BLACK, null, null)));
        commandField.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;");

        pane.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane, commandField);

        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Debug Console");
        stage.show();

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss] ");
        commandField.requestFocus();
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        message = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + message;
        ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getChildren()
            .get(0)).getContent()).getChildren().add(textBuilder(message));
    }

    public void write(String message, Priority priority) {
        write(message, priority.color);
    }

    private void write(String message, Color fontColor) {
        message = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + message;
        ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getChildren()
            .get(0)).getContent()).getChildren().add(
            textBuilder(message, null, null, 0, fontColor));
    }

    public void write(Exception exception, Priority priority) {
        // exception.printStackTrace();
        write("--- Beginning of Exception ---", Priority.HIGH);
        write(exception.toString(), priority);
        StackTraceElement[] arrayOfStackTraceElement = exception
                .getStackTrace();
        Object localObject2;
        for (StackTraceElement ste : arrayOfStackTraceElement)
            write("\t at " + ste, priority);
        localObject2 = exception.getCause();
        if (localObject2 != null)
            write("Caused by: " + localObject2);
        write("--- End of Exception ---", Priority.HIGH);
    }

    private HBox textBuilder(String text) {
        return textBuilder(text, null, null, 0, null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private HBox textBuilder(String text, FontWeight fontWeight,
            FontPosture fontPosture, double fontSize, Color fontColor) {
        return javafx.scene.layout.HBoxBuilder
                .create()
                .children(
                        javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxBuilder.create().build(),
                        javafx.scene.text.TextBuilder
                                .create()
                                .text(text)
                                .font(Font
                                        .font("Consolas",
                                                (fontWeight == null ? FontWeight.NORMAL
                                                        : fontWeight),
                                                (fontPosture == null ? FontPosture.REGULAR
                                                        : fontPosture),
                                                (fontSize <= 0 ? 13 : fontSize)))    
                                .wrappingWidth(
                                        ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot())
                                                .getWidth() - 2)
                                .fill((fontColor == null ? Color.WHITE
                                        : fontColor)).build()).build();
    }

    public int clear() {
        int items = ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot())
                .getChildren().get(0)).getContent()).getChildren().size();
    ((VBox) ((ScrollPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getChildren()
                .get(0)).getContent()).getChildren().clear();
        return items;
    }

    public static enum Priority {
        /**
         * A message of no great importance
         */
        LOW(Color.LIGHTGRAY),
        /**
         * A message of standard importance, or something not necessary to be
         * noticed
         */
        NORMAL(Color.WHITE),
        /**
         * A message of standard importance, but may need developer attention
         */
        MILD(Color.YELLOW),
        /**
         * A message needing attention, as something may have broken
         */
        MEDIUM(Color.ORANGE),
        /**
         * A message of great importance, something broke, an exception was
         * thrown, ect.
         */
        HIGH(Color.RED);

        private Color color;

        private Priority(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The above code is able to be copied into an IDE and be executed. Does anyone have any idea as to why the formatting gets all wonky?

Comment: Post a [mcve] not links to code on another site

Comment: @Reimeus Updated the main question with a more compact version of the code. However, everything listed above is needed for a successful compilation/run.

Comment: Unrelated, but builders are deprecated, you should probably refactor your code not to use them.  Also, you might consider using FXML and injecting references to your controls into an FXML controller rather than using really deep getChildren statements with casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to understand what your code is trying to do, because of all the strange casts etc. Doesn't calling both [`setFitToWidth(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#fitToWidthProperty) and [`setFitToHeight(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#fitToHeightProperty) on a `ScrollPane` make the `ScrollPane` redundant?

If the aim is to let the `ScrollPane` use any additional space available to the `VBox`, you can call

```
VBox.setVgrow(scrollPane, javafx.scene.layout.Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: To reiterate what @jewelsea mentioned in the comments above, you need to get rid of the builder classes, which are [deprecated](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html) and will be completely removed in a future version (possibly as soon as Java 9).